# How to ensure all string literals are unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-literals

I have a fairly large python code base to go through. It's got an issue where some string literals are strings and others are unicode. And this causes bugs. I am trying to convert everything to unicode. I was wondering if there is a tool that can convert all literals to unicode. I.e. if it found something like this:

```
print "result code %d" % result['code']
```

to:

```
print u"result code %d" % result[u'code']
```

If it helps I use PyCharm (in case there is an extension that does this), however I am would be happy to use a command like too as well. Hopefully such a tool exists.

Comment: Why not `u"result code %d"` as well?

Comment: you could always use Python 3 :)

Comment: @unutbu You are absolutely right. I edited the question to include that. Silly me.

Comment: `from future import unicode_literals`? But it's entirely possible that the problem isn't string literals but other sources of byte strings (e.g. "wrong" choice of API, or missing `encode`/`decode` calls).

Comment: @MattDMo sadly we are using some 3rd party libraries that are only supported for Python 2

Comment: @delnan That worked great. I'd love to run a script over the source and make everything consistent and then tell people to always do unicode strings. But this seems to fix some of the places I found as bugs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [tokenize.generate_tokens](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.generate_tokens) break the string representation of Python code into tokens. `tokenize` also classifies the tokens for you. Thus you can identify string literals in Python code.

It is then not hard to manipulate the tokens, adding `'u'` where desired:

---

```py
import tokenize
import token
import io
import collections

class Token(collections.namedtuple('Token', 'num val start end line')):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return token.tok_name[self.num]

def change_str_to_unicode(text):    
    result = text.splitlines()
    # Insert a dummy line into result so indexing result
    # matches tokenize's 1-based indexing
    result.insert(0, '')
    changes = []
    for tok in tokenize.generate_tokens(io.BytesIO(text).readline):
        tok = Token(*tok)
        if tok.name == 'STRING' and not tok.val.startswith('u'):
            changes.append(tok.start)

    for linenum, s in reversed(changes):
        line = result[linenum]
        result[linenum] = line[:s] + 'u' + line[s:]
    return '\n'.join(result[1:])

text = '''print "result code %d" % result['code']
# doesn't touch 'strings' in comments
'handles multilines' + \
'okay'
u'Unicode is not touched'
'''

print(change_str_to_unicode(text))
```

yields

```
print u"result code %d" % result[u'code']
# doesn't touch 'strings' in comments
u'handles multilines' + u'okay'
u'Unicode is not touched'
```

Comment: This worked out great. Many thanks for putting this answer together.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (uses regex), and it's shorter than @unutbu's solution.
But there's s loop hole, the strings containing `#` won't work with this.

```py
import re
scode = '''
print "'Hello World'" # prints 'Hello World'
u'Unicode is unchanged'"""
# so are "comments"'''
x1 = re.compile('''(?P<unicode>u?)(?P<c>'|")(?P<data>.*?)(?P=c)''')

def repl(m):
    return "u%(c)s%(data)s%(c)s" % m.groupdict()

fcode = '\n'.join(
      [re.sub(x1,repl,i)
       if not '#' in i
       else re.sub(x1,repl,i[:i.find('#')])+i[i.find('#'):]
       for i in scode.splitlines()])
print fcode
```

Outputs:

```py
print u"'Hello World'" # prints 'Hello World'
u'Unicode is unchanged'
# so are "comments"
```

For `#` I have this (and it's longer than @unutbu's solution :| )

```py
import re
scode = '''print "'Hello World'"  # prints 'Hello World'
u'Unicode is unchanged'
# so are "comments"
'#### Hi' # 'Hi' '''

x1 = re.compile('''(?P<unicode>u?)(?P<c>'|")(?P<data>.*?)(?P=c)''')

def in_string(text,index):
    curr,in_l,in_str,level = '',0,False,[]

    for c in text[:index+1]:
        if c == '"' or c == "'":
            if in_str and curr == c:
                instr = False
                curr = ''
                in_l -= 1
            else:
                instr = True
                curr = c
                in_l += 1
        level.append(in_l)
    return bool(level[index])

def repl(m):
    return "u%(c)s%(data)s%(c)s" % m.groupdict()

def handle_hashes(i):
    if i.count('#') == 1:
        n = i.find('#')
    else:
        n = get_hash_out_of_string(i)
    return re.sub(x1,repl,i[:n]) + i[n:]

def get_hash_out_of_string(i):
    n = i.find('#')
    curr = i[:]
    last = (len(i)-1)-''.join(list(reversed(i))).find('#')
    while in_string(curr,n) and n < last:
        curr = curr[:n]+' '+curr[n+1:]
        n = curr.find('#')
    return n

fcode = '\n'.join(
    [re.sub(x1,repl,i)
     if not '#' in i
     else handle_hashes(i)
     for i in scode.splitlines()])

print fcode
```

Output:

```py
print u"'Hello World'"  # prints 'Hello World'
u'Unicode is unchanged'
# so are "comments"
u'#### Hi' # 'Hi'
```

Comment: I discourage the use of regular expressions to parse/manipulate irregular languages like Python, especially since there’s a perfectly fine Python parser included in the language’s standard library. Hence -1.